# C++ Template type cheking

Tags: c++, templates, types

```
class Nation{
      private :
        string  continent;
        string  pays;
        string  capital;
        long    superficie;
        long    population;

      public :
        static const string CONTINENT ;
        static const string PAYS      ;
        static const string CAPITAL   ;
        static const long   SUPERFICIE;
        static const long   POPULATION;
    .....
    const string Nation::CONTINENT ="1";
    const string Nation::PAYS      ="2";
    const string Nation::CAPITAL   ="3";
    const long   Nation::SUPERFICIE= 4;
    const long   Nation::POPULATION= 5;
    ....
        template <class T>
        void Nation::setField(T fieldType, T valeur){
            if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->CAPITAL).name()){
                if (fieldType==this->PAYS     ) this->pays      = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->CAPITAL  ) this->capital   = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->CONTINENT) this->continent = valeur;
            }
            else if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->SUPERFICIE).name()){
                if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
            }
        }
    .......
    }
```

The compiler said that there is some errors: `"[Error] no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_string<char>' and 'const long int')"`
at the line:

```
if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
```

It's a compile error not run time.

Calling the function:

```
country1.setField(Nation::PAYS, "CANADA");
country1.setField(Nation::POPULATION, 12345678);
```

I appreciate you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates don't work this way, you can't suddenly 'change' the type from an if to another. What you can do is make overloads:

```
void Nation::setField(string fieldType, string valeur){
                if (fieldType==this->PAYS     ) this->pays      = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->CAPITAL  ) this->capital   = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->CONTINENT) this->continent = valeur;
            }

void Nation::setField(long fieldType, long valeur){
                if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
            }
```

Some further comments:

- Take string function parameters as const reference
- Try to use `switch()` instead of `if()` (works in the second case)
- Depending on your use case, you might want to convert the string to field index separately. You definitely want to do this if you access the same field twice.

Comment: Thank you.
You are really fast (y)

Answer (score 3):

That's the (problem) with templates, they get evaluated at compile time, and so conditions like `if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->CAPITAL).name())` don't "protect" the subsequent evaluation of the template.

What happens is, that when you call

```
country1.setField(Nation::PAYS, "CANADA");
```

`T` gets resolved (at compile time) to a `const char*`, and so the type of `fieldType` will be a `const char*`. Then, in this branch

```
else if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->SUPERFICIE).name()){
                if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
                if (fieldType==this->POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
            }
```

even though this will not get executed, because `fieldType` doesn't have the same type as `SUPERFICIE`, this is not known at compile time. Basically, you are comparing `fieldType` (which is a `const char*`) with `SUPERFICIE` (which is a `long`), and there is no implicit comparator function to do that conversion, and so the compiler throws an error.

What you could do:

- Specialize `setField` for `long` and `const char*`
- Use 2 overloaded functions (`const char*` and `long`) instead of the template alltogether

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would declare your constants as an enum and make the first argument of your function that type.  There is no need to make the indicator the same type as the field you are trying to store.

Second, as others have pointed out, overloaded functions better fit what you're trying to work with.  Templates actually create overloaded functions behind the scenes before compile time, and then compile them.  Consequently, what you have written actually looks more like this to the compiler:

```
void Nation::setField(int fieldType, int valeur){
    if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->CAPITAL).name()){
        if (fieldType==this->PAYS     ) this->pays      = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->CAPITAL  ) this->capital   = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->CONTINENT) this->continent = valeur;
    }
    else if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->SUPERFICIE).name()){
        if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
    }
}

void Nation::setField(string fieldType, string valeur){
    if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->CAPITAL).name()){
        if (fieldType==this->PAYS     ) this->pays      = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->CAPITAL  ) this->capital   = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->CONTINENT) this->continent = valeur;
    }
    else if(typeid(fieldType).name()==typeid(this->SUPERFICIE).name()){
        if (fieldType==this->SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
        if (fieldType==this->POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
    }
}
```

Looking closely, you can see how the compiler is going to complain.

So to further modify your code to with enums would look like this:

```
...
enum FieldType {CONTINENT, PAYS, CAPITAL, SUPERFICIE, POPULATION};

void Nation::setField(FieldType fieldType, string valeur){
     if (fieldType==FieldType::PAYS)     this->pays      = valeur;
     if (fieldType==FieldType::CAPITAL)  this->capital   = valeur;
     if (fieldType==FieldType::CONTINENT)this->continent = valeur;
}

void Nation::setField(FieldType fieldType, long valeur){
    if (fieldType==FieldType::SUPERFICIE) this->superficie = valeur;
    if (fieldType==FieldType::POPULATION) this->population = valeur;
}
...
```

The compiler will automatically decide which function to call based on the type of value passed to the valeur parameter.  From there, all you have to do is decide where to store the value.

Comment: Really very good explication, Thank you. 
I think I can not use it for getField function.

Comment: @MalusJan  True.  C++ does not allow you to overload functions with only differing return types.  At least one parameter must be different as well.

I would suggest just creating similarly named functions like getFieldInt and getFieldString.  Within those functions, you can use a switch statement to return the valid fields for that type and throw a logic error in the default section.  That would lead to a runtime error, but as long as you test all types of fields, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Meta:** As other solutions already given aswer to solve the problem as it is, I think looking at this problem with another perspective can be benificial for both OP and others who will look at this question later.

If you only care about the semantics of calling the methods, you could do this, which is not only faster, but much more flexible:

```
struct Nation {
private :
    string  continent;
    string  pays;
    string  capital;
    long    superficie;
    long    population;

public :
    static const constexpr auto CONTINENT = &Nation::continent;
    static const constexpr auto PAYS = &Nation::pays;
    static const constexpr auto CAPITAL = &Nation::capital;
    static const constexpr auto SUPERFICIE = &Nation::superficie;
    static const constexpr auto POPULATION = &Nation::population;
};
```

Now, implementing the `setField` function becomes trivial. The only implementation you will need is this:

```
template<typename Member, typename V>
void setField(Member m, V&& value) {
    this->*m = std::forward<V>(value);
}
```

Then, you can call you function like this:

```
Nation country1;

country1.setField(Nation::PAYS, "CANADA");
country1.setField(Nation::POPULATION, 12345678);
```

If compile-time reflection would be available, it would even be possible to generate the pointers automatically.

**EDIT:** Here's a quick explaination of the concepts used here.

The technique I used with the `&&` and `std::forward` is called *perfect forwarding*. This is used to andle move semantics or copy semantics in a generic way. You can check what are *forwarding references* or *universal references*.

The interesting part is the use of *pointer to members*. A pointer to member act like an alias of a member of a class. In other words, instead of using a member of a class directly, you can use an alias; you can use a pointer to member.

When used with a particular instance, a pointer to member will act just like if you access the member pointed by the member. They are used with the operator `.*` or the operator `->*`. The left hand of the operator is the object, and the right and is the pointer to member.

In my examples, `CONTINENT`, `PAYS` and others points to the associated member.

You can read more about poiter to member here: [Pointers_to_data_members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) and here: [operator_member_access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators)

Comment: It seems really sophisticated method but I understand nothing.
It's really complicated.
`void steField(Member m, V&& value) {
    this->*m = std::forward<V>(value);
}`
Would you mind explain it?